# Should you create new website or create virtual directories under it

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis, iis-6

When creating **new websites** on `IIS 6`, should you create a **virtual directory** under Default Website or create a **new website**? Why would you do one over the other?

I am creating new `asp.net` websites and `web services`, mainly running .NET 2.0.

Comment: "It depends". What are your goals? For instance, do you need to use multiple host names for the sites, or will they all use the same host name? Will they use different ports?

Comment: Same port and same host name, so they will look like http://hostname/servicename/service.asmx or .svc etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create virtual directories, then all your "websites" will be running under 1 app pool. If one is hanging, they all hang.

If you only have 1 IP, then if you don't use virtual directories, you'll have to assign each website a different port (can't all be using default port 80).

Comment: You can create new app pools though, and assign each new virtual directory to that app pool?